# mysql: find parent "domain name"

Tags: mysql

My SQL query returns "subquery returns more than 1 row" error.   To avoid "X-Y" problem I will omit what my query is, just focus on the data structure and what I want to achieve.

Sample Data:

| fqdn |
| --- |
| location.country1.city1.district1 |
| location.country1.city1 |
| location.country1 |
| location.country2.city2.district2 |
| location.country2.city2 |
| location.country2 |
| location.country3.city3.district3 |
| location.country3.city3 |
| location.country3 |

by some sub-query I got two row of data, say `location.country1.district1` and `location.country2.district2`.  My purpose is to get all rows of their "parents", i.e., `location.country1`, `location.country1.city1`, `location.country2`, ... etc.

My query looks like:

```
SELECT fqdn FROM table WHERE CONCAT(fqdn, '.%') LIKE (sub-query which returns multiple rows)
```

Which of course generated that error.   So, I can do this in pure (one-line) SQL query?

Thanks!

Comment: Avoid the X part of the problem, don't make it a sub-query. `SELECT fqdn FROM table t JOIN other_table o ON t.location LIKE CONCAT(o.zzzz, '%') WHERE o.xxx=yyy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT /* DISTINCT */            -- uncomment if you need unique fqdn only
       fqdn_table.fqdn 
  /* , subquery.outputcolumn */  -- uncomment if you want to know 
                                 -- what subq. row matches to what fqdn
FROM fqdn_table 
JOIN (subquery which returns multiple rows) AS subquery
WHERE LOCATE(fqdn_table.fqdn, subquery.outputcolumn) = 1
```

Comment: Cool. Very clever solution